# Hive query executing differently in Hive client and JDBC

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive, cloudera

The following query I executed via Hive client, Java program JDBC and beeline.

```
SELECT
*
FROM
    TABLE_ONE AS t1
    JOIN TABLE_TWO t2 ON t2.p_id = t1.p_id 
        AND t2.p_n_id = t1.p_n_id 
        AND t2.d_id = t1.d_id
    JOIN TABLE_THREE t3 ON t3.d_m_id = t1.d_m_id
        AND t3.d_p_id = t1.d_p_id
    JOIN TABLE_FOUR t4 ON t4.c_id = t1.c_id
    JOIN TABLE_FIVE t5 ON t5.a_n_id = t1.a_n_id
    JOIN TABLE_SIX t6 ON t6.d_p_p_s_id = t1.d_p_p_s_id
        AND t6.a_v_id = t1.a_v_id
        AND t6.p_f_id = t1.p_f_id
```

While executing via Hive cilent, it has got completed in 21sec, where as Java program JDBC and beeline took around 110sec and 200sec respectively.

Here is how I got Hive Connection in JDBC

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://<ip address of hive gateway server>:10000/default?zeroDateTimeBehavior=round").
```

- Hive client completed it with only one mapper.
- Java JDBC and beeline executed 5 MR job. Each MR job took 2 mappers and 1 reducer.

Here is the row counts for each table.

- TABLE_ONE has 44981 records.
- TABLE_TWO has 2173 records.
- TABLE_THREE   has 1415 records.
- TABLE_FOUR has 249 records.
- TABLE_FIVE has 168   records.
- TABLE_SIX has 255 records.
- OUTPUT has 33362 records.

I want Hive client performance in JDBC. Any suggestion?

**Hive version is 0.13.1 (Cloudera 5.3.3)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few suggestions which can help you debug :

The properties set when running from beeline client & through JDBC.

I suspect the property `hive.auto.convert.join` is causing this behavior.

Basically from beeline it is able to read all the smaller tables (two to six)  in memory of each mapper and use it for join. But in second case it executes a Mapper to read each input.

Try to set `hive.auto.convert.join` to true. You may also have to play around with : `hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask` & `hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask.size`.

HTH.